# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cypress-react-selector'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cypress

I am trying to use [@cypress/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/react) and I followed the installation instructions. In addition, I have also installed [Cypress Testing Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/cypress) to use Testing Library extensions for Cypress.

When the cypress is started, I have got the following error messages:

```
./node_modules/@cypress/react/support/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cypress-react-selector' in '/home/developer/project/example/webapp/board-ui/node_modules/@cypress/react/support'
resolve 'cypress-react-selector' in '/home/developer/project/example/webapp/board-ui/node_modules/@cypress/react/support'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /home/developer/project/example/webapp/board-ui/node_modules/@cypress/react/package.json (relative path: ./support)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    Looked for and couldn't find the file at the following paths:
[/home/developer/project/example/webapp/board-ui/node_modules/@cypress/react/support/node_modules]
[/home/developer/project/example/webapp/board-ui/node_modules/@cypress/node_modules]
```

Do I have to install cypress-react-selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just install the missing package [cypress-react-selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-react-selector).

```
npm i --save cypress-react-selector
```

I'm not sure if it's supposed to be installed with @cypress/react or Cypress Testing Library, if so it would be worthwhile reinstalling those and watch out for error messages during the install.